# Will a tug-of-war battle damage my climbing rope

Tags: everyday-life, elasticity

I plan to organize a big tug-of-war with a climbing rope (70m long) with 50-60 adults. I know the climbing rope is elastic. The rope resistance is 9 kN when a chock occurs.

Will the rope breaks or become unsafe after such a game ?

Comment: Would you trust your life to a climbing rope that had been trampled in a muddy field?

Comment: @JohnRennie in fact, the field will be clean, that's not the main issue

Comment: @JohnRennie Probably a better answer than mine, even though a comment. I only answered for the sake of saying DON'T EVEN THINK ABOUT DOING THIS, I don't care a jot about the physics here!

Comment: Just use a rope that is depricated for climbing purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't even think about this!! REALLY. The risk is probably low, but the outcome of a broken rope is pretty severe in climbing. Too severe for the sake of a tug of war game.

This is an advanced materials engineering question. 9kN is presumably the rope's rating, right? 50-60 grownups will easily impart this force onto the rope (30 at each end, each pulling with 300N). Even so, I should think that it would withstand the game in the sense that the rope would not break during the game.

However, how the game affects your rope's safety is an advanced materials engineering question. Crucial to your question is whether the rope leaves its elastic (linear) regime under the load and whether the fibres begin to deform. Unless the rope stays perfectly elastic, or very near thereto, its load bearing capacity will be compromised by the game.

I would advise buying a rope especially for your tug of war game. There are 60 grown ups to split the cost over, so anything else strikes me as a bit foolhardy.

Comment: Why do you think it won't break? 9k N is the breaking point, right?

Comment: @Yashbhatt 9kN is its safe rating. Especially for things like climbing ropes there is always a big margin of safety. A 1cm thick manilla rope is really strong: one can easily tow a car of several tonnes: even though of course the rope bears nothing like this, it can withstand severe jerking by a not too careful letout of the clutch, it takes a lot to break one. Synthetic ropes are even stronger. The question to me is a clear one of risk versus benefit though, and that makes it a no brainer to me even though the likelihood of a mishap is probably small.